# Let  be a Log-Normally distributed RV with  = 3 and  = 2. Determine [max( − 100, 0)]

Tags: distributions, lognormal-distribution

See the question above. I am not quite sure, if my result is correct, because I do not have any solutions.
I tried with the following formula:

$$
E[X] = e^{\mu+\frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2}} \cdot \Phi\left(\frac{\ln \left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)+\mu+\sigma^{2}}{\sigma}\right)-\alpha \cdot \Phi\left(\frac{\ln \left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)+\mu}{\sigma}\right)
$$

What is the correct result?

Comment: Forgot to mention, my result is 24.403

Comment: What's $\alpha$?

Comment: $\alpha = 100$ (given in title)

Comment: Thanks; there's a 100 in the title but no indication there that it's $\alpha$